# PHP Array of Arrays

Tags: php

I have an array of arrays in PHP like below

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array 
  ( 
  [SEQ] => 2 
  [CODE] => cd1 
  [DESC] => desc1 
  ) 
[1] => Array 
  ( 
  [SEQ] => 7 
  [CODE] => cd2 
  [DESC] => desc2 
  ) 
)
```

I want to convert it to like below. It should pick up the SEQ value and CODE value and assign them as the corresponding key and value

```
Array(
"2" => cd1,
"7" => cd2
)
```

Comment: And you want us to code it for you? Have you tried anything?

Comment: do you want to lose all the `desc`riptions ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$array = array(
    array('SEQ' => 2, 'CODE' => 'cd1', 'DESC' => 'desc1'),
    array('SEQ' => 7, 'CODE' => 'cd2', 'DESC' => 'desc2'),
    array('SEQ' => 10, 'CODE' => 'cd3', 'DESC' => 'desc3')
);

$result = array();
foreach ($array as $row) {
    if (isset($row['SEQ']) && isset($row['CODE'])) {
        $result[$row['SEQ']] = $row['CODE'];
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

### Output:

```
Array
(
    [2] => cd1
    [7] => cd2
    [10] => cd3
)
```

Comment: This option is a much better more guarded version of the one I posted... this should be the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you assuming the array in question is $ret

```
$ret = array(); 
foreach($array as $val){
    $ret[$val["SEQ"]] = $val["CODE"];
}
```